# How i insert into in SQL using 2 Rows?

Tags: sql-server

first table like this :- `Car_id` , `Car_Model`, `Car_type`
`car_id` is a `PK`

second table like this :- `car_id`, `job_number`, `date`, `current_dist`, `Prev_dist` 
 `car_id` is a `FK`

i want insert new value in second table using `car_id` and `job_number`

Comment: guys i will try explain what i want ..

Comment: looks like you want to update the second table based on car_id and job_number?

Comment: OK, i can say i have car_id = 12345 in table car , and i insert this car_id in the second table and i write job_number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In select query in place of `job_number`, `date`, `current_dist`, `Prev_dist` u should give the actual values to insert in table

```
INSERT INTO Test1 (car_id, job_number, [date], current_dist, Prev_dist)
SELECT car_id,
       job_number,
       [date],
       current_dist,
       prev_dist
FROM Test
WHERE car_id = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The query will be like

```
INSERT INTO second_Table (car_id, job_number, date, current_dist, Prev_dist)
SELECT car_id,
       job_number,
       [date],
       current_dist,
       prev_dist
FROM first_Table
WHERE car_id = value
```

In this query job_number,date,current_dist, prev_dist will have the actual values and car_id will come from first_Table

**For example** : Suppose job_number = 123, date = '2015-12-08 05:52:53.717',current_dist = 123,prev_dist = 234. then the query will be like

```
INSERT INTO second_Table (car_id, job_number, date, current_dist, Prev_dist)
SELECT car_id,
       123,
       '2015-12-08 05:52:53.717',
       123,
       234
FROM first_Table
WHERE car_id = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in oracle

In select query in place of job_number, date, current_dist, Prev_dist u should give the actual values to insert in table

```
INSERT INTO Test1 (car_id, job_number, [date], current_dist, Prev_dist)
SELECT car_id,
       job_number,
       [date],
       current_dist,
       prev_dist
FROM Test
WHERE car_id = value;
```

Comment: Please remove the duplicate of your answer